Como agregar una marca de agua a una foto en flutter?
tengo problemas con esta función de dart donde quiero guardar una foto tomada por el usuario con una pequeña marca de agua que indique la fecha, la foto se toma y es guardada, sin embargo lo hace sin la marca de agua, esta es mi función, uso las dependencias image, image_picker e image_gallery_saver:
Future<void> _saveImageToGallery(
  String imagePath, GoodFeature goodDetails, String nowDate) async {
final File imageFile = File(imagePath);
final Uint8List imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();

// Decodificar la imagen usando la librería "image"
img.Image? originalImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
if (originalImage == null) {
  print("Error al decodificar la imagen");
  return;
}

// Definir el texto que se añadirá (la fecha)
String dateText = "Fecha: ${nowDate.substring(0, 10)}";

// Dibujar el texto sobre la imagen
img.drawString(originalImage, dateText, // El texto a añadir
    font: img.arial24, // Fuente embebida en el paquete 'image'
    x: 10, // Posición X
    y: 10, // Posición Y
    color: img.ColorFloat16.rgb(255, 255, 255) // Color blanco
    );

// Convertir la imagen modificada a bytes nuevamente
Uint8List modifiedImageBytes =
    Uint8List.fromList(img.encodeJpg(originalImage, quality: 60));

// Guardar la imagen modificada en la galería
final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(modifiedImageBytes,
    quality: 60, name: "${goodDetails.name}_${nowDate.substring(0, 10)}");

print("Imagen guardada");
print(result); // Puedes verificar si la imagen se guardó correctamente

}

Si usas la librería https://pub.dev/packages/image puedes modificar la imagen seleccionada de la siguiente forma:
Future<dynamic> _addWatermark() async {
 if (_image == null) return;

 final imageBytes = await _image!.readAsBytes();
 img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes));

 if (image == null) return;
 String watermarkText = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();

 int fontSize = 30;
 img.drawString(image, img.arial_24, 20, 20, watermarkText);

 final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
 final imagePath = '${directory.path}/watermarked_image.png';
 File watermarkedImage = File(imagePath)
  ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(image));

 return watermarkedImage;

}

